# Why UIImage reference change when i give animation to UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, nsoperationqueue

I want to animate images on multiple UIImageViews.Image is coming from server side with Url so i request url and convert it in to image and i give animation to uiimageview i.e. crossdissolve , one issue is occured image reference is changing in UIImageView means first time it's displaying different images and when i scroll then other image display on same UIImageView.This problem will occur only for the first time because i maintain imagecache.Any idea  about this bahavious ?. Below is code that i used.

```
-(void)requestForImage:(NSString*)strURL{

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    NSURLRequest *request;
    NSString * newImageURL = [strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newImageURL]];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
    {
         UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

         if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil && image)  //If  success
         {
             //receive data
             [[myImage sharedMyclass] setImage:image withKey:strURL];

             dispatch_queue_t queue_ = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
             dispatch_async(queue_, ^{

                 UIImage *image = [[myImage sharedMyclass] imageForURL:strURL]; //That return image from particular path

                 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(receivedImage:) withObject:image waitUntilDone:NO];

                 [data writeToFile:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:strURL] atomically:YES];

                 dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


                     [UIView transitionWithView:self
                                   duration:2.0
                                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                                 animations:^{
                                         self.image = image;

                                     }
                                     completion:NULL];
                     self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                 });
             });
         }

     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call that function, the compiler checks the code, and then the machine makes it happen.

That means => all the tasks written in the system's task list, but no one can promise you which one of them will be done first.

My advice, divide it to few little functions, 
Then call the first one [self perform...], and then make a block inside every function completion section, and inside that block assign the picture into array, and call to the next function (the next desired picture).

That's how no other picture will be assigned as long as the current request is done.